# simple http post request in java with json post parameters

Tags: java, http, post

Hi i have no idea about java, but for testing purpose i need some  code to do http post request with json parameters in java. I have collected few examples and written the code below but its not working.

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class pojo1
{
 String name=abc;
 String age=18;
 //generate setter and getters
}

 public class SimpleURL
{
 String postUrl="www.site.com";// put in your url
 Gson gson= new Gson();
 HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postUrl);
 StringEntity  postingString =new StringEntity(gson.toJson(pojo1)); //convert to json
 post.setEntity(postingString);
 post.setHeader("Content-type","application/json");
 HttpResponse  response = httpClient.execute(post);
}
```

File name: SimpleURL.java
compilation in linux:  javac SimpleURL.java
Error:

```
SimpleURL.java:22: <identifier> expected
post.setEntity(postingString);
          ^
SimpleURL.java:22: <identifier> expected
post.setEntity(postingString);
                        ^
SimpleURL.java:23: <identifier> expected
post.setHeader("Content-type","application/json");
          ^
SimpleURL.java:23: illegal start of type
post.setHeader("Content-type","application/json");
           ^
SimpleURL.java:23: illegal start of type
post.setHeader("Content-type","application/json");
                          ^
```

Comment: explain more what you wanted to do

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't compile. In order to compile, you just need to put the code from SimpleURL in a main method as following :

```
public class SimpleURL{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String postUrl="www.site.com";// put in your url
        Gson gson= new Gson();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postUrl);
        StringEntity  postingString =new StringEntity(gson.toJson(pojo1)); //convert to json
        post.setEntity(postingString);
        post.setHeader("Content-type","application/json");
        HttpResponse  response = httpClient.execute(post);
    }
}
```

You also need to change `www.site.com` to be the target website.
`pojo1` should not be declared `public`. You can keep it in the same file though.

Answer (score 0):

your code does not compile, probably because you've defined 2 public class in the same file.

```
public class pojo1
public class SimpleURL
```

Comment: i have done necessary changes still i get the error, http://pastebin.com/pmEggF94

Comment: you should have two java files one to declare yout pojo1 class in a file named pojo1.java, and the other for SimpleURL in in a file named SimpleURL.java